# Unknown parameter usage CloudKit - iOS 10

Tags: cloudkit, ios10

Does anyone know what the `String` field is intended for in this closure `public var recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock: ((CKRecordID, String) -> Void)?`. I have no idea what it is for, and the documentation is incomplete at the moment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second parameter of [CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckfetchrecordzonechangesoperation)'s `recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock` is the **recordType** of the deleted CKRecord.

The Objective-C declaration is:

`@property(nonatomic, copy, nonnull) void (^recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock)(CKRecordID *recordID, NSString *recordType);`

(A tip for the new documentation is that the Swift declaration does not always list variable names (ex. for tuples), but [the Objective-C declaration does](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckfetchrecordzonechangesoperation/1640470-recordwithidwasdeletedblock?language=objc). In cases where the documentation is currently incomplete, this can be quite handy.)